# Pass a string to function get an integer array from it

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Hello this is my code and i am pretty confused about it.
I am passing a string to a function and I am making an integer array which I need to use in the main function. I am a newbie and I want to learn how to take out arrays in these types of situations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *encrypt (char string[]);
char string[1000];
int intstring[10000], last;

int main()
{
gets(string);
encrypt(string[1000]);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
    printf("%d ", intstring[i]);
}
}
int * encrypt(char string[])
{
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
{
    if (string[i] >= 65 && string[i] <= 90)
    {
        string[i] = string[i] - 65;

    }
    else if (string[i] >= 97 && string[i] <= 122)
    {
        string[i] -= 96;

    }
    else if (string[i] == 32)
    {
        string[i] -= 6;
    }
    else if (string[i] == 46)
    {
        string[i] -= 19;
    }
    intstring[i] = string[i];
 }
 return intstring;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "take out arrays"?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If `intstring` is global you don't need to return it.

Comment: You should [pass the array](https://www.google.nl/search?q=c+pass+array) to your `encrypt` function as an extra argument. There are 100s examples out there how to do that (follow the link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused some things here.
This:

```
int intstring[10000]
```

is global array so there is no need to return it from function you could directly access it in main as you are doing.

This:

```
encrypt(string[1000]);
```

is also wrong, you must call it like this:

```
encrypt(string);
```

You can also pass length as separate parameter if you desire.

Comment: i did it, it did the job but I am still unable to print the integer array in the main function.

Comment: @FahadRana: why not? It ran ok with me when I entered: "hello"
 it printed: 8 5 12 12 15. (after I made changes I told you).

Answer (score 1):

So, several things in no particular order:

First, **NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets`; it *will* introduce a point of failure into your code.  Use `fgets` instead.  As of the 2011 standard, it has been removed from the standard library.  Don't use it.

Second, you want to avoid using globals if you can help it.  Ideally, functions should communicate exclusively through parameters and return values (and exceptions where they're supported).  You can change your function such that it takes both `string` and `intstring` as arguments, like so:

```
void encrypt( char *string, int *intstring)
{
  // body of encrypt
}
```

Note that since you're passing `intstring` as an argument, you dont need to return it, so I've typed the function to return `void`.  The call from `main` would look something like:

```
int main( void )
{
  char string[10000];
  int  intstring[10000];
  ...
  encrypt( string, intstring );
  ...
}
```

Also note the types of the function parameters; when you pass an array expression as a function argument, it "decays" from type "array of `T`" to "pointer to`T`".  And when you pass the array arguments, you only need to specify the name; `string[10000]` refers to the next character past the end of the `string` array.

In the body of your `encrypt` function, you are modifying the contents of `string` and simply copying the result to `intstring`; are you sure that's what you want to do?  Are you sure you don't want to preserve the original contents of `string`?

Comment: I am actually making a mini version of RSA encryption as an assignment. Until now, the code below has been done and now the problem is at pow function. i guess the problem is with the datatype.

Comment: Here's the code:
    char string[1000];
    int intstring[10000],arrayP[10000],arrayC[10000],last,lastp,e=17,
    n=3233, d = 2753;
    main(){
    fgets(string, stdin);encrypt(string);
 last++;
 if (last%2==0)
 {
 for (int j=0, i = 0; i < last; i=i+2,j++)
 {
 arrayP[j] = (intstring[i]*100)+intstring[i+1];lastp = j;
 }
 }
 else{
 intstring[last] = 26;
 for (int j = 0, i = 0; i <= last; i = i + 2, j++)
 {arrayP[j] = (intstring[i] * 100) + intstring[i + 1];
 lastp = j;
 }}
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastp; i++){
    arrayC[i] = pow(arrayP[i], e) % n; // problem.
    }
 //...print arrays

Comment: @FahadRana: 'pow` takes `double` arguments and returns a `double`, which can't be an operand of the `%` operator.  You either need to convert the result of `pow` to an int *before* using the `%` operator, or use the [remainder](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/remainder/) function instead.

Comment: What f I do this (arratP[i]^e)%n ? will it do the job?

Answer (score 0):

When passing the array to the function, you don't need to give the subscript. So change that into like this.

```
encrypt(string);
```

After that You don't need to return the global array. So you can use function as void returning datatype.

```
void encrypt (char string[]);
```